# Angular CLI and CSS url resolving

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a misunderstanding on my part, but I'm having trouble figuring this out.

I generate a new Angular (6.1.8) project with CLI (6.2.3), copy an image file (let's call it `pic.jpg`) in `src/assets/`, and modify the default app.component files so that all it has is a div with a background-image from CSS:

```
div {
    background-image: url('assets/pic.jpg');
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Running `ng build` gives me the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.css (Emitted value instead of an
instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: C:\tmp\so-demo\src\app\app.component.css:2:28:
Can't resolve 'assets/pic.jpg' in 'C:\tmp\so-demo\src\app'
```

I suppose it can't resolve that, since the `assets` folder is in `src`, not in `src/app`. "Ok", I hear you say, "just prefix it with '/' so the path isn't relative". I guess that could work for web deployed applications, but this is supposed to be run with Electron using file:// and `<base href="./">` in whatever folder, and as such having `url('/assets/pic.jpg');` makes it search for `c:\assets\pic.jpg` which of course doesn't work unless the whole app is in the drive root.

I can work around this by using `url('../assets/pic.jpg');`, but that makes the CLI copy the image file to root dir (so I'll have two copies, one in root and one in `assets` folder of the output) and modify the style so that it becomes just `url('pic.jpg');`. This can't be the right solution? There were some bug reports over at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/ regarding somewhat similar issues, but they were all closed.

Comment: This `url('../assets/pic.jpg');` will make a copy to the assets folder of the dist. If you not want to have this you have to upload your file to the server with an url and link to that one.